If $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$, then there exist $f,g$ s.t. $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[f,g] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$
I ran into this MSE question and would like to ask about its answer and plausible generalizations.
The quoted MSE question asks if the following claim is true or false and why:
Claim: Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$. Then there exist $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[f,g] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Remarks:

Maybe it is also assumed that $\mathbb{C}(a,b,c)=\mathbb{C}(x)$, I am not sure.
If at least one of $\{a,b,c\}$ already belongs to the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by the other two, then trivially the claim holds; indeed, if w.l.o.g. $c \in \mathbb{C}[a,b]$, then $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c]=\mathbb{C}[a,b]$, and we can take $f=a, g=b$.
Therefore, one has to prove the claim under the additional assumption that each of $\{a,b,c\}$ does not belong to the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by the other two (is this possible?).

My questions are divided into two cases: $k[x]$ and $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 2$.

Case I: $k[x]$.
Question 1: Is the proof correct?
Question 2: The proof also says: "You can probably prove this claim with elementary methods. (Hint: show that the codimension of $\mathcal{O}$ in $\mathbf{C}[x]$ is $1$ and then analyze what this means)." Is it possible to prove the claim with elementary methods?
Question 3: Where it was needed to assume that the base field is $\mathbb{C}$? Is it possible to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any field $k$ of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed? I guess that a field of positive characteristic would cause problems, although I have not yet checked this.

Case II: $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 2$.
Let us write the quoted question in different notations:
Let $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\mathbb{C}[f_1,f_2,f_3] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$. Then there exist $g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{C}[f_1,f_2,f_3] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[g_1,g_2] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Notice that the answer is negative in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: Given $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, it is not necessarily true that there exist $g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{C}[f_1,f_2,f_3] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[g_1,g_2] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$; take for example $f_1=x^2, f_2=x^3, f_3=y$, there are no $g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
$\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3,y] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[g_1,g_2] \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Question 4: Concerning more variables, we can ask the following:
Assume that $f_1,\ldots,f_n,f_{n+1},f_{n+2} \in A_n=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ are such that each $f_j \notin \mathbb{C}[f_1,\ldots,f_{j-1},f_{j+1},\ldots,f_{n+2}]$
and $\mathbb{C}[f_1,\ldots,f_{n+2}] \subsetneq A_n$.
Is it true that there exist polynomials $g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1} \in A_n$ such that $\mathbb{C}[f_1,\ldots,f_{n+2}] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1}] \subsetneq A_n$?
Also same question with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by any field $k$ of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed.

I have asked some of the above questions here, but have not received comments.
Thank you very much!
Edit: Here there is an explanation about a claim that appears in the answer to the above quoted MSE question.
Edit 2: This paper partially answers my questions; I have just found it.

In $\mathbb{C}[x]$: $f_1=x^4+x^2, f_2=x^3+x, f_3=x^5$. What are $g_1,g_2$? According to the answer, $\mathbb{C}[x^4+x^2,x^3+x,x^5]$ is contained in an algebra isomorphic to ${h \in \mathbb{C}[x] | h(0)=h(1) }$. Here $f_1=x^4+x^2=x^2(x^2+1), f_2=x^3+x=x(x^2+1)$, so $\mathbb{C}(f_1,f_2)=\mathbb{C}(x)$, so $\mathbb{C}(f_1,f_2,f_3)=\mathbb{C}(x)$ -- see the first remark. But I do not see how $\mathbb{C}[x^4+x^2,x^3+x,x^5]$ is contained in an algebra isomorphic to ${h \in \mathbb{C}[x] | h(0)=h(1) }$.

Or a simpler example $f_1=x^2, f_2=x^3+x, f_3=x^5$. Of course $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3+x,x^5]$ is not contained in $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$, since we are not able to obtain $f_2=x^3+x$, so as in the above example we conclude (from the answer to the quoted  MSE question) that $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3+x,x^5]$ is contained in a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra isomorphic to ${h \in \mathbb{C}[x] | h(0)=h(1) }$.

Notice that in the second example $f_2^2=(x^3+x)^2=x^6+2x^4+x^2 \in \mathbb{C}[x^2]=\mathbb{C}[f_1]$. However, it seems that $f_2 \notin \mathbb{C}[f_1,f_3]=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^5]$.

In your second example we have $x^3=f_1f_2-f_3$, so subtracting this from $f_2$ we get $\mathbb C[f_1,f_2,f_3]=\mathbb C[x]$.

@AndrewHubery, thank you very much!

Are there any maximal proper sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras of $\mathbb{C}[x]$, other than those of the form $\mathbb{C}[(x-a)(x-b), x(x-a)(x-b)]$? (Both for $a=b$ and $a \neq b$?) I can't think of any.

@DavidESpeyer, thank you for your helpful comment! It is the algebraic explanation to the quoted MSE question, the explanation I was looking for. Your form contains the two general types: (1) $a=b$: if $a=b=0$ then $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$. (2) $a \neq b$: if $a=0,b=1$ then $\mathbb{C}[x(x-1),x^2(x-1)]$. Please, it seems that it is not a problem replacing $\mathbb{C}$ by any field $k$ of characteristic zero; am I missing something?

I think I see now that the base field should be algebraically closed or at least contain square roots.

Also, concerning the number of generators of the given proper subring, it is not important how many generators are, but just that it is a proper subring, and then it is contained in a maximal subring https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580932/every-commutative-subring-is-contained-in-a-maximal-commutative-subring?rq=1

Of course, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is not relevant, since we consider sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras.
